# Removing DOM element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a custom error script that displays custom error messages on a page if a user tries to submit a form and it fails validation.

On the focusout of the input element (the input that failed validation) I am trying to remove the DOM element I added, but its removing all of the DOM elements with the class name I specify that exist on the page.

Adding the DOM element:

```
$('#' + el).closest('tr').addClass('pink_bg');
var error_txt = $('#' + el).attr('rel');
$('#' + el).before('<span class="registration_error_message">' + error_txt + '</span>');
```

Attempting to remove the DOM element (this removes all of the DOM elements of class="registration_error_message"), all I want to do is remove one of the elements:

```
$("#" + el).focusout(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove('[class^=registration_error_message]');
    $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('pink_bg red_border');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're adding the `.registration_error_message` element before the `el` element using [jQuery's `.before()` method](http://api.jquery.com/before/), it would seem that you want to [use `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) instead of  [using `.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) when removing.

```
$(this).prev().remove('[class^=registration_error_message]');
```

Or

```
$(this).prev('[class^=registration_error_message]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different traversal method to get what you're after.  Since you're adding it as a previous sibling with [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/), use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
$(this).siblings('.registration_error_message').remove();
//or more specific:
$(this).prev('.registration_error_message').remove();
```